# Pandas pd.ExcelWriter options={'strings_to_numbers': True} having an issue

Tags: python, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I am using the following code but it is transforming more than expected

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path_out+file_name_out,engine='xlsxwriter',options={'strings_to_numbers': True})
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='blabla', index=False)
```

For instance, value `57_345` gets changed to `57345`, removing "_". Working fine on numeric and ok with alpha but just issue with that use case.
Anyone got this issue before?
Thanks.

Comment: the program cannot find the `num` equivalent for `_`

Comment: Could you add some sample data to your example to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @jmcnamara: value 057_345 gets changed to 57345 whereas as AA_BB stays the same and numeric like 0111 is correctly updated.

Answer (score 0):

Python added support for [underscores in numeric literals](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/) in Python 3.6. So now you can write 1234567 as 1_234_567 so that the number is clearer.

A consequence of this is that strings like "57_345" will be converted to a number using `float()`

```
$ python
Python 3.6.6 (default, Aug 16 2018, 00:18:32)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin

>>> float("57_345")
57345.0
```

This is the conversion that XlsxWriter uses when the `strings_to_numbers` option in enabled so "57_345" gets converted to a number.

If you want to avoid this, and other false positives, you should turn off (or just omit) this option. If you need to convert string data to numbers where there is a possibility for misinterpretation you should handle that separately in Pandas or Python.